# How to fix image alignment using bootstrap4?

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have a section where i want to make it like given below image:-
[image]

There is alignment issue image should be always attached with left and right corner as given in image. Now i'm using `bootstrap container` for this.

My Code:-

```css
.p-relative {
    position: relative;
}

.p-static {
    position: static;
}

.img-1 {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0px;
    left: 0;
}
.img-2 {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0px;
    left: 0;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <title>Bootstrap Example</title>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.4.1/css/bootstrap.min.css">
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.5.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.16.0/umd/popper.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.4.1/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>

<section class="pt-5 pb-5 p-relative">
    <div class="container p-static">
<div class="row">
    
      <div class="col-6 p-static">
        <img src="https://i.stack.imgur.com/Lrz2v.jpg" class="img-1 img-fluid" alt="">
      </div>
      <div class="col-6 pl-5">
        <h3>Heading</h3>
        <p>Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged. </p>
      </div>
      </div>
      
      <div class="row">
    
     
      <div class="col-6 pl-5">
        <h3>Heading</h3>
        <p>Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged. </p>
      </div>
       <div class="col-6 p-static">
        <img src="https://i.stack.imgur.com/Lrz2v.jpg" class="img-2 img-fluid" alt="">
      </div>
      
      </div>
      
      
    </div>
</section>

</body>
</html>
```

Answer will be appropriated, Thank You!

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure whether you need to use `position: absolute`, so I've wrote this without using it.

```
<section class="pt-5">
    <div class="container-fluid">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-6">
                <img src="https://i.stack.imgur.com/Lrz2v.jpg" class="w-100" alt="">
            </div>
            <div class="col-6 m-auto pl-5">
                <h3>Heading</h3>
                <p>Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged. </p>
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="row mt-5">
            <div class="col-6 m-auto">
                <div class="w-75 float-right">
                    <h3>Heading</h3>
                    <p>Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged. </p>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="col-6">
                <img src="https://i.stack.imgur.com/Lrz2v.jpg" class="w-100" alt="">
            </div>
        </div> 
    </div>
</section>
```

There are still some padding on both sides, coming from `class="container-fluid"`. There are solutions to that: either totally remove the `container-fluid` or just make it like so: `container-fluid pl-0 pr-0`. I hope it does what you need or at least give you some insight of the matter.

Comment: i have to use container because this is content area. i cant avoid it

Answer (score 0):

you can just add px-0 on your image div to disable col default padding.

```
<section class="pt-5 pb-5 p-relative">
        <div class="container p-static">
            <div class="row">

                <div class="col-6 p-static px-0">
                    <img src="https://i.stack.imgur.com/Lrz2v.jpg" class="img-1 img-fluid" alt="">
                </div>
                <div class="col-6 pl-5">
                    <h3>Heading</h3>
                    <p>Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been
                        the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley
                        of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It has survived not only five centuries,
                        but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged. </p>
                </div>
            </div>

            <div class="row">


                <div class="col-6 pl-5">
                    <h3>Heading</h3>
                    <p>Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been
                        the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley
                        of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It has survived not only five centuries,
                        but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged. </p>
                </div>
                <div class="col-6 p-static px-0">
                    <img src="https://i.stack.imgur.com/Lrz2v.jpg" class="img-2 img-fluid" alt="">
                </div>

            </div>


        </div>
    </section>
```

Comment: don't add position style.

Answer (score 0):

I have removed all the position settings as I think they are not necessary. I used the bs4 `no-gutters` and `pt-5` classes to set margin and padding to align the image and text.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <title>Bootstrap Example</title>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.4.1/css/bootstrap.min.css">
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.5.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.16.0/umd/popper.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.4.1/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
</head>

<body>

  <section class="pt-5 pb-5">
    <div class="container">
      <div class="row no-gutters">

        <div class="col-6">
          <img src="https://i.stack.imgur.com/Lrz2v.jpg" class="img-fluid" alt="">
        </div>
        <div class="col-6 pl-5">
          <h3>Heading</h3>
          <p>Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book.
            It has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged. </p>
        </div>
      </div>

      <div class="row no-gutters">


        <div class="col-6 pl-5 pt-5">
          <h3>Heading</h3>
          <p>Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book.
            It has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged. </p>
        </div>
        <div class="col-6 pt-5">
          <img src="https://i.stack.imgur.com/Lrz2v.jpg" class="img-fluid" alt="">
        </div>

      </div>


    </div>
  </section>

</body>

</html>
```

I have updated the code to attach the images to the left and right section.

```css
.img-fluid {
  width: 100%;
  height: 80% !important; /* You may edit the height accordingly */
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <title>Bootstrap Example</title>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.4.1/css/bootstrap.min.css">
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.5.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.16.0/umd/popper.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.4.1/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
</head>

<body>

  <section class="pt-5 pb-5">
    <div class="container-fluid px-0">
      <div class="row no-gutters">

        <div class="col-6">
          <img src="https://i.stack.imgur.com/Lrz2v.jpg" class="img-fluid" alt="">
        </div>
        <div class="col-6 pl-5">
          <h3>Heading</h3>
          <p>Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book.
            It has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged. </p>
        </div>
      </div>

      <div class="row no-gutters">


        <div class="col-6 pl-5">
          <h3>Heading</h3>
          <p>Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book.
            It has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged. </p>
        </div>
        <div class="col-6">
          <img src="https://i.stack.imgur.com/Lrz2v.jpg" class="img-fluid" alt="">
        </div>

      </div>


    </div>
  </section>

</body>

</html>
```

Comment: still pictures are not attached with left and right section like given screenshot in question.

Comment: @RohitVerma I have updated the code to attach to left and right section.

Comment: now image is ok but now text is not ok i dont want this please see screenshot properly which is given in question there is image with left and right but content should be in container area.